# Qual diferença entre form-group e input-group bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Qual a diferença? em que casos são usado um ou o outro?

Answer (score 1):

o `form-group` é utilizado em uma div que conterá os objetos de um formulário,
ele será um 'GRUPO de Inputs', sendo assim conseguimos por exemplo agrupar um rótulo com um input como a seguir:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

já o `input-group` é para unirmos dois objetos independentes e formarmos um só, é como ter uma caixa de texto unida com um rótulo dando a impressão que se trata de um unico objeto.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Entre com o email">
</div>
```